# Retrieve Dynamically-Created SVG Element

Tags: javascript, svg, onclick

I have a form section where a user can enter in data and then a chart is created based off of the data. I want the user to be able to copy the SVG of the chart to the clipboard so that they can then paste the chart in another field on the form, but I'm unsure of how to retrieve what I need as the SVG is dynamically created. Below is the button that, when clicked, is intended to copy the SVG to the clipboard.

```
<div style="float: right;" class="printnoshow">
    <input type="button" class="formbutton" value="Copy" onclick="copyImg(); $('.formsmodalmask').hide(); $('.pmonitormodal').hide(); $('.pmonitordescriptiondiv').css('page-break-after', 'auto');" />
</div>
```

When clicked the JavaScript function copyImg() is intended to retrieve the SVG. I have an outline below, but am unsure of where to go with this.

```
function copyImg() {
    var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
    console.log(svg);

    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(svg);

    window.getSelection().addRange(range);

    var success = document.execCommand('copy');
    if (success)
        console.log('Successfully copied to clipboard');
    else
        console.log('Unable to copy to clipboard');

    window.getSelection().removeRange(range);
}
```

So the SVG is the chart below and you can see the Copy button on the form as well. Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJPFZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

The first answer 100% correct but it will copy the svg as raw text to the clipboard.
If you search for a solution where you really save the svg as an Image.
You need to use html2canvas.min.js as an extrenal src.
Like this:

```
<script src="https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/v1.0.0-rc.3/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
```

And and the script:

```
svg = document.querySelector('svg');
svg.onclick = () => {
html2canvas(svg).then(function(canvas) {
                canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                        navigator.clipboard
                                .write([
                                new ClipboardItem(
                                        Object.defineProperty({}, blob.type, {
                                                value: blob,
                                                enumerable: true
                                        })
                                )
                        ])
                });
        });
}
```

This will copy the svg as an image so you can paste it everywhere. So after that you are able to paste it into MS Word etc.
And of course you can wrapt it into a function to use the code if you have some async stuff (after creating the svg). PS: Maybe you need to edit the css selector

Comment: You are correct. The SVG element is now retrieved properly. Using everything below html2canvas(svg) is not rendering the image properly when pasted, however.

Comment: Where do you paste the image. In my case I tested it in MS Word with a small polygon as svg. and it works good. You you tell me more information e.g. where you paste it,  svg as raw, which browser are you using?

Comment: Pasted into word as well and got a blank image rather than the chart. Using Chrome.

Comment: If you add `console.dir(svg);` after you queried the svg what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the easiest way to get at the markup of a dynamically created svg is to read its [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) attribute. This gives you a string which you can easily copy to the clipboard.

The following snippet illustrates a way to do that (a click on the svg copies its markup to the clipboard):

```js
const svg = document.getElementById('svg');

svg.onclick = () => window.navigator.clipboard.writeText(svg.outerHTML);
```

```css
svg {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" />
  <rect x="90" y="90" width="10" height="10" />
</svg>
```

Comment: In my case though, I'm unsure of how to get the element itself. You created an svg element yourself and could then use document.getElementById('svg'), but I have nothing defined as this. So when I run what I currently have, document.getElementById('svg') is null.

Comment: @CDAtheProgrammer If the svg is the only one on the page you could use `document.querySelector('svg')`. Otherwise you need to figure out a way to add an id to your svg or identify it some other way.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The first line shows console.log(svg) and the rest is console.dir(svg), which shows all of the properties shown plus many more below those.
[image]